# Is there a way to create an object using a pre-existing object as a sub-object of the first in C++?

Tags: c++, class, object, inheritance, nested

So, say we have `class Parent`, and `class Offspring` that inherits from `class Parent`. To my understanding, when I create an `Offspring` object, a `Parent` object is also created and associated with the `Offspring` object. The thing is, if I have already created an independent `Parent` object, can I use that as the `Parent` object that's contained within an `Offspring` object at the time of its creation?

I.e. Is it possible not to create a new `Parent` object within the `Offspring` object, and use the original (and independent) in its place instead? Just copying over the data of the original `Parent` object over to the one that's created within the `Offspring` one is obviously not what I want.

Comment: This only makes sense if `Parent` is actually an interface. Then `ParentImpl` could implement the interface and have state. `Offspring` could then implement the `Parent` interface using a provided `ParentImpl`.

Comment: You could try letting the offspring object take an rvalue reference to the parent object in its constructor, and move-constructing the parent from that rvalue reference.

Comment: The very existence of the question suggests yours is a case where composition (specifically dependency injection) would be a better design than inheritance. It happens a lot...

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to **derive** `Offspring` from `Parent` at all.  `Offspring` should contain a **pointer/reference** to a separate `Parent` object instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: There is no reason an `Offspring` couldn't also be a `Parent`.

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to change a Parent to an Offspring?

Comment: @jxh: If you want `Offspring` to be a `Parent` of its own `Offspring` objects, then `Parent` should be defined as an interface instead of its own class.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: As I had stated in the top comment.

Answer (score 4):

It is sort of possible to do this. If Parent has a move constructor, then you can write something like this:

```
class Offspring : public Parent {
  double m_x;
 public:
  Offspring(Parent && p, double x)
      : Parent(std::move(p))
      , m_x(x) 
  { }
}
```

I think this is about as close as you can get without doing something kind of dangerous and sketchy. While this technique probably can't avoid copying the data of Parent, it can be much more efficient. For example, if Parent was std::vector, then the code above would initialize the base of Offspring by moving from an existing vector. This would entail moving just 24 bytes worth of data, as opposed to all the data the vector points to.

I think you may want to read more above move semantics and see how it fits it with your class.

Comment: the same principle works with the copy constructor instead of the move constructor.

Comment: Well this is just the same as copying over the data and destroying the original . (Of course , there is no other option)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is to be able to use an existing `Parent` instance with multiple `Offspring`. I say this, because you seem concerned by copying, which normally should be of no concern.

You can define `Parent` to be a pure interface, and an implementation of the interface itself to represent a stand alone parent.

```
struct Parent {
    virtual ~Parent () = default;
    virtual void foo () = 0;
    //...
};

class Mother : public Parent {
public:
    void foo () { /* ... */ }
    //...
};
```

Then, your `Offspring` can accept a `Parent` to delegate the implementation.

```
class Offspring : public Parent {
    Parent &p_;
public:
    Offspring (Parent &p) : p_(p) {}
    void foo () { p_.foo(); }
    //...
};
```

So now, a `Mother` can be the parent of multiple `Offspring`.

```
Mother m;
Offspring o1(m);
Offspring o2(m);
```

Comment: In this case, I wouldn't *derive* `Offspring` from `Parent` at all.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: From a functionality point of view, I agree. But from an object relationship model, there is no reason `Offspring` could not be a `Parent`.

Comment: I woudl agree, if `Parent` is defined as an abstract interface and not a concrete class of its own, yes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: My answer text should have made it clear `Parent` should be a pure interface.

Comment: Not sure whether or not this is what the question asked, but in any case I would never recommend a relative beginner to code this way. This is a dangling reference waiting to happen, and can only be justified in special circumstances. Maybe use shared pointers instead?